# Lodash code optimization/refactoring

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

This is the original JSON data:

```
var data= [
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'Test',       subArea: 'Dev',     done: 10 },
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'Test',       subArea: 'QA',      done: 10 },
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'Test',       subArea: 'Support', done: 10 },
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'External',   subArea: 'Dev',     done: 5  },
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'External',   subArea: 'QA',      done: 5  },
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'External',   subArea: 'Support', done: 5  },
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'Dev',     done: 20 },
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'QA',      done: 20 },
      { project: "ABC",    area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'Support', done: 20 },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'Test',       subArea: 'Dev',     done: 20 },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'Test',       subArea: 'QA',      done: 20 },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'Test',       subArea: 'Support', done: 20 },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'External',   subArea: 'Dev',     done: 10 },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'External',   subArea: 'QA',      done: 10 },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'External',   subArea: 'Support', done: 10 },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'Dev',     done: 5  },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'QA',      done: 5  },
      { project: "ABC123", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'Support', done: 5  },
    ];
```

What I need is to group items by **project**, divide them in **areas** and sum the **done** hours for each **subarea**. The new JSON result must be like this:

```
    [
   {
      "name": "ABC",
      "test": {
         "total": 30,
         "totalDev": 10,
         "totalQA": 10,
         "totalSup": 10
      },
      "external": {
         "total": 15,
         "totalDev": 5,
         "totalQA": 5,
         "totalSup": 5
      },
      "escalation": {
         "total": 60,
         "totalDev": 20,
         "totalQA": 20,
         "totalSup": 20
      }
   },
   {
      "name": "ABC123",
      "test": {
         "total": 60,
         "totalDev": 20,
         "totalQA": 20,
         "totalSup": 20
      },
      "external": {
         "total": 30,
         "totalDev": 10,
         "totalQA": 10,
         "totalSup": 10
      },
      "escalation": {
         "total": 15,
         "totalDev": 5,
         "totalQA": 5,
         "totalSup": 5
      }
   }
]
```

With my actual code bellow I'm already getting the result I want, but I think the code could be more optimized. Without repetition, and all the conditional verification's, without hard code the area and subareas properties inside the map block, because these values area dynamic in the server-side.

```
var sum = (total, item) => total += item.done;

result = _.chain(data)
          .groupBy(function(value) { return value.project })
          .map((projectGroup, projectName) => ({ 
                  name: projectName,
                  test: {
                      total:    _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'Test')) , sum, 0),
                      totalDev: _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'Test' && o.subArea === 'Dev')) , sum, 0),
                      totalQA:  _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'Test' && o.subArea === 'QA')) , sum, 0),
                      totalSup: _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'Test' && o.subArea === 'Support')) , sum, 0)
                  },
                 external: {
                      total:    _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'External')) , sum, 0),
                      totalDev: _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'External' && o.subArea === 'Dev')) , sum, 0),
                      totalQA:  _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'External' && o.subArea === 'QA')) , sum, 0),
                      totalSup: _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'External' && o.subArea === 'Support')) , sum, 0)
                  },
                  escalation: {
                      total:    _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'Escalation')) , sum, 0),
                      totalDev: _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'Escalation' && o.subArea === 'Dev')) , sum, 0),
                      totalQA:  _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'Escalation' && o.subArea === 'QA')) , sum, 0),
                      totalSup: _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === 'Escalation' && o.subArea === 'Support')) , sum, 0)
                  }       
    }))
```

Comment: `.groupBy(function(value) { return value.project })` could simply be `.groupBy('project')`

Comment: why is abc test totaldev = 30? where does the number come from?

Comment: I edited, now its correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea what you want to optimize here, lodash should do it instead of you. I have only one remark

```
var sum = (total, item) => total += item.done;
function reduceData(projectGroup, projectName, comparationLabel) {
   return {
     total:    _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === comparationLabel)) , sum, 0),
     totalDev: _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === comparationLabel && o.subArea === 'Dev')) , sum, 0),
     totalQA:  _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === comparationLabel && o.subArea === 'QA')) , sum, 0),
     totalSup: _.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, (o) => ( o.area === comparationLabel && o.subArea === 'Support')) , sum, 0)
   }
}
result = _.chain(data)
          .groupBy(function(value) { return value.project })
          .map((projectGroup, projectName) => ({ 
                  name: projectName,
                  test: reduceData(projectGroup, projectName, 'Test'),
                  external: reduceData(projectGroup, projectName, 'External'),
                  escalation: reduceData(projectGroup, projectName, 'Escalation')    
    }))
```

And yes, you can avoid of `_.filter(projectGroup, (o)` if you will do some kind of cache, but you will save small count of program resources.

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than nesting like this:

```
_.reduce(_.filter(projectGroup, ...), sum, 0)
```

You can do this to prevent looping over the collection twice:

```
_(projectGroup).filter(...).reduce(sum, 0).value()
```

Comment: Thanks! I will make the change.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a single loop in plain Javascript for grouping and summing the hours?

This proposal uses a hash table and groups by the value of `project` property.

```js
var data = [{ project: "ABC", area: 'Test', subArea: 'Dev', done: 10 }, { project: "ABC", area: 'Test', subArea: 'QA', done: 10 }, { project: "ABC", area: 'Test', subArea: 'Support', done: 10 }, { project: "ABC", area: 'External', subArea: 'Dev', done: 5 }, { project: "ABC", area: 'External', subArea: 'QA', done: 5 }, { project: "ABC", area: 'External', subArea: 'Support', done: 5 }, { project: "ABC", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'Dev', done: 20 }, { project: "ABC", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'QA', done: 20 }, { project: "ABC", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'Support', done: 20 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'Test', subArea: 'Dev', done: 20 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'Test', subArea: 'QA', done: 20 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'Test', subArea: 'Support', done: 20 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'External', subArea: 'Dev', done: 10 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'External', subArea: 'QA', done: 10 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'External', subArea: 'Support', done: 10 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'Dev', done: 5 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'QA', done: 5 }, { project: "ABC123", area: 'Escalation', subArea: 'Support', done: 5 }],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var area = a.area.toLowerCase(),
        subArea = 'total' + a.subArea;

    if (!this[a.project]) {
        this[a.project] = { name: a.project };
        result.push(this[a.project]);
    }
    this[a.project][area] = this[a.project][area] || { total: 0 };
    this[a.project][area][subArea] = (this[a.project][area][subArea] || 0) + a.done;
    this[a.project][area].total += a.done;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code is really good and solved my problem, but I just feel more comfortable using Lodash for now.